# How to combine fractions using octave symbolic?

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

Does anyone know how to get *Octave* to combine fractions in the symbolic package? For example, I would like to make `"1+1/s"` rewritten as `"(s^2 + 1)/s"`.

My reason is that I want to get zeros and poles of frequency domain expressions into the right place in the rational expression. The above is a very simple example of a more complicated use case, typically with lots of R, L, C constants.

Comment: I guess that you mean `(s+1)/s` and not `(s^2+1)/s`. You can use the function `factor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `factor()`, in this case it will simply put the whole expression with the same common denominator:

```
syms x,s

x = 1+1/s
res = factor(x)
```

and

```
res =   
s + 1
─────
  s
```